# How to sum up **ALL** values on a given date in a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, date, time

I have a stopwatch project in C#. I will start recording time and store it in my database in a "Timespan" column. I also have a "Timestamp" column which records the date that the time was recorded.

Now I want to have a store procedure to give the program a date and I want my program to search the database and sum up **`ALL`** values in every corresponding "Timespan" columns on the given date. In other words If I give it a date I want my program to look up every "Timestamp" column cells and if there is one or more timestamp equal to the given date I want the program to go ahead and check all of their related "Timespan" columns and sum them up.

what I tried:(which works if there is only one timestamps value equal to the given date. it throws error for more than 1 value)
This is the error:

> Additional information: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is
>   not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when
>   the subquery is used as an expression.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SumOnDateReport
    @QueryDate DATETIME
AS
    DECLARE @total_sec INT
    DECLARE @HourTime INT
    DECLARE @MinTime INT
    DECLARE @SecTime INT

    SET @HourTime = (SELECT CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 1, 2)) 
                     FROM InfoTable 
                     WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate)
    SET @MinTime = (SELECT CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 3, 2)) 
                    FROM InfoTable 
                    WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate)
    SET @SecTime = (SELECT CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 5, 2)) 
                    FROM InfoTable 
                    WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate)

    SET @total_sec = @HourTime * 3600 + @MinTime * 60 + @SecTime

    INSERT INTO InfoTable(TotalSecColumn) VALUES (null)

    UPDATE InfoTable 
    SET TotalSecColumn = @total_sec
    WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate

    SELECT TotalSecColumn 
    FROM InfoTable
    WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate
```

all of my table columns are NVARCHAR but Time`stamp`column is datetime.

Comment: What ***datatype*** is this `TimeStampColumn` in your table??

Comment: @marc_s its datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close. An integer variable can only accept a single value. To get the single value, you group and sum on each of the sub selects:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SumOnDateReport @QueryDate nvarchar(50) AS DECLARE @total_sec INT DECLARE @HourTime INT DECLARE @MinTime INT DECLARE @SecTime INT

SET @HourTime = (SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 1, 2))) 
                 FROM InfoTable 
                 WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate
                 GROUP BY TimeStampColumn) * 3600
SET @MinTime = (SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 3, 2))) 
                FROM InfoTable 
                WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate
                GROUP BY TimeStampColumn) * 60
SET @SecTime = (SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 5, 2))) 
                FROM InfoTable 
                WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate
                GROUP BY TimeStampColumn)
SET @total_sec = @HourTime + @MinTime  + @SecTime

INSERT INTO InfoTable(TotalSecColumn) VALUES (null)

UPDATE InfoTable 
SET TotalSecColumn = @total_sec
WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate

SELECT TotalSecColumn 
FROM InfoTable
WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a `DATETIME` column - you should **refrain** from trying to *guess* the string format (there's no default, system-inherent string representation - so your code would always depend on the language/regional settings) - use the proper `DATETIME` function to deal with this!!

Change your code (those three `SET` statement with the `CONVERT` and `SUBSTRING`) into something like this:

```
SELECT 
    @HourTime = SUM(DATEPART(HOUR, TimeStringColumn)),
    @MinTime = SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, TimeStringColumn)),
    @SecTime = SUM(DATEPART(SECOND, TimeStringColumn))
FROM 
    InfoTable 
WHERE 
    TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate
```

This should work just fine with multiple rows for the same `@QueryDate`, too!

Comment: Im getting TimeSpan  columns values from label.text in C#. so I have to use NVARCHAR in my table and substring to do the rest things... isnt there any way to solve my problem with my time span column being a nvarchar?

Comment: @absolute455: I don't understand - your code clearly shows you're loading this stuff *from the database* - not from a text lable ......

Comment: my code in sql is a storeprocedure. it gets the "QueryDate" from my c# program. my c# program contains labels. it gets QueryDate from those labels. which are texts. @marc_s

Comment: Although I tried to convert the labels.texts into dates to be able to use your code but i was not successfull because when they are converted they are all turned to 12:00 AM. I dont know how to fix it